# How to get start and end of month in numeric type for SQL where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to run a query monthly to look for records from the previous month. The where clause will be greater or equal to the 1st day of the month and less or equal to the last day. The difficultly I am having is the dates are stored as numbers in a column with a numeric data type. The format being used is yyyymmdd. We are currently manually changing the where clause, so e.g. show me any records with dates >=20201001 to <=20201031, but we need to automate this process. I have tried a few ways to try and solve this but need some guidance.
So far I've tried:

```
select concat( CONCAT(cast((Year(DATEADD(month, -1, getdate()))) as numeric),cast((Month(DATEADD(month, -1, getdate()))) as numeric)),'01')
```

Returns error message operand data type numeric is invalid for concat operator. Works in separate query window returning format yyyymmdd.

```
SELECT DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, (DATEADD(month, -1, getdate()))), 0)
```

Returns error message arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type date time. Works partly in separate query window but returns yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss:ms

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Databases don't have "records".

Comment: `The difficultly I am having is the dates are stored as numbers in a column with a numeric data type.` that's a bug. Use the proper type, `date`. You can get the end-of-month for a specific date with `EOMONTH`.

Comment: why ow why would anyone store dates in another type then a datetime type ? You should fix that first, you will only run into more troubles if you dont

Comment: What you have now isn't even numeric, it's the numeric representation of a *string*. You have to convert that to a string before you can parse it as a date, eg `cast(cast(thatField as varchar(8)) as date)`

Comment: @GuidoG actually, one should use `date`, `datetime2` or `datetimeoffset`. `datetime` is a rather quirky legacy type

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, when I type  a `datetime type` I mean any of the existing datetime types, like `date`, `datetime`, `datetime2` or `datetimeoffset`. I guess that was not very clear I agree about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real solution is fix the design; don't store dates in a datatype  other than a date and time data type.

What you can do, however, is convert the value of `GETDATE()` to a numerical value of the same format:

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE NumericalDate >= CONVERT(varchar(8),DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1)),112)
  AND NumericalDate < CONVERT(varchar(8),DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE())),112)
```

For today, this would return rows where `NumericalDate` is in November 2020 (specifically on or after `20201101` and before but *not* on `20201201`).

*Note, I don't "bother" to `CAST`/`CONVERT` the `varchar` to a Numerical data type, as it'll be implicit cast due to data type precedence.*

Comment: Thanks Larnu, unfortunately the data supplied to us in the format yyyymmdd and the database was built with to accommodate this, hence the data type being numeric and not a datetime type.
I've used the code and sql server writes it as below:

>= (SELECT CONVERT (varchar(8), DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(DATEADD(month, - 1, GETDATE()), - 1)), 112) AS Expr1)
< (SELECT CONVERT (nvarchar(8), DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), - 1)), 112) AS Expr1)

This doesn't throw any errors, but it isn't returning any results either, even though I know there are rows in this range. Any ideas?

Comment: *"even though I know there are rows in this range"* Clearly are mistaken as this works as expected [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7f780c576edcf4a1f5c98f53f23eb3e3).

Answer (score 0):

You can use artihmetics like so:

```
where dates >= year(getdate()) * 10000 + month(getdate()) * 100 + 1
  and dates < year(dateadd(month, 1, getdate())) * 10000 + month(dateadd(month, 1, getdate())) * 100 + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare the month and forget the days.

BETWEEN 20201000 and 20201099 finds the same rows as your example >=20201001 to <=20201031

That means that you do not have to figure out how many days are in the month.